# Visual Studio Code keyboard shortcut to switch to "Editor Layout > Single"

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, if we click on the menu item for "Editor Layout > Single", it reduces all split panes and columns to one pane, putting all open editors from all previous panes into tabs on that one pane.

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this or a way to bind one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(On Mac) Go to Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts (or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>). There's a command called `workbench.action.editorLayoutSingle`, and you can add a binding for this.